# Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie in Ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: vpn, openconnect

I am trying to connect VPN and getting the error

```
SSL connection failure
Failed to open HTTPS connection to my.vpn.com
Failed to obtain WebVPN cookie
```

Tried multiple workaround but no success.

Comment: Post openconnect version, your exact command, and the full output.